# What is <array name> + <constant> in scanf()?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Well I got a code from my friends.
I had looked at the code several time. 
I didn't understand it process at all and some weird syntax.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int n, input[1000], i, j, k, max = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
       scanf("%d", input + i);
       if(input[i] > max) 
          max = input[i];
    }
   for(i = 1; i <= max; i++){
       for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
           if(input[j] + i <= max)
             for(k = 0; k < input[j] * 2; k++) 
                putchar(' ');
           else{
             for(k = 0; k < input[j]; k++){
                if(max - i == k)
                    putchar('/');
               else 
                    putchar(' ');
             }
             for(k = input[j] - 1; k >= 0; k--){
               if(max - i == k)
                    putchar('\\');
               else 
                    putchar(' ');
             }
         }
     }
     putchar('\n');
  }
  getch();
  return 0;    
}
```

What is `input + i` after `scanf` and how does this program works (I'm a slow learner)?

Comment: It is the same as `scanf("%d",&input[i]);`

Comment: The first thing I'd say about this code is that the indentation is broken and a bag full of spaces wouldn't hurt either. It's quite hard to read this way.

Comment: Bosaba Hexor: Now observe the difference between [you posted](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/cc0d2a06-0173-4d7b-8d9d-af2839325ae0/view-source) and [update code](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/512f5f9f-81d1-44b1-8896-29fc2fafe13a/view-source) with proper indentation, spaces.

Answer (score 10):

In the expression `input + i`, `input` is an array. When used in an expression, the name of an array is converted into a pointer to the first element of the array. Adding `i` to `input` pointer results in a pointer to the `i`<sup>th</sup> element of the array. A clearer way to write the same thing would be `&input[i]`.

And hence the simple way to write equivalent scanf is:

```
scanf("%d", &input[i]);
```

Point is  the expression `input[i]` is equivalent to `*(input + i)`.

And expression `&input[i]` is equivalent to `&*(input + i)` or just `(input + i)`, that is what scanf need is address of `i`<sup>th</sup> element.

To understand read [10.2 `Pointers` and `Arrays`; Pointer Arithmetic](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10b.html) and [Pointer Arithmetic](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html).

Comment: It may be better to say "is converted to" instead of "decays". Maybe. Not certainly.

Comment: @ElchononEdelson I am not sure, but `decay` is commonly used term for array expression...  yes I read here on wiki *"This is one of the few exceptions to the rule that the name of an array is converted to a pointer to the first element of the array"*...

Comment: Decay _is_ a commonly used term, yes, but it's not used by the C standard, and I believe that under some circumstances it can confuse people. (And, as I said, it _may_ be better. I don't claim that it _is_ better.)

Comment: @ElchononEdelson Doesn't it confusing here? If you think feel free to correct my English..thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider this alternate wording: "`input` is an array. When used in an expression, the name of an array is converted into a pointer to the first element of the array. Adding `i` to this pointer results in a pointer to the `i`th element of the array. A clearer way to write the same thing would be `&input[i]`."

Comment: @ElchononEdelson Yes very nice! Thanks you.. I update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`<array name>` + `<integer>` in expression `input + i` evaluates to the memory address where the `scanf()` function will put the scanned integer from the stdin.